# possible to copy from one remote computer to another remote computer using smbclient?

Tags: samba, file-copy, smb

So I know how to use smbclient to copy a file from a remote server to my local computer similar to this:

```
sudo smbclient //192.168.105.250/sharename --user='<user>%<pwd>' -c 'cd import\addemployees;put /var/path/to/local/file/_output/2017/04/28/hour_07/New_Employee_Report_105.csv New_Employee_Report_105.csv;'
```

This works perfectly. However, is there a way to use smbclient to copy a file directly from 1 remote computer to another remote computer on one line? Example:

- I have file1 on Computer A
- I want to put file 1 on Computer Z
- Computer A can't see Computer Z, but they can both see Server1

Would I always have to copy file1 to Server1 and then copy it from Server1 to Computer Z, or can I go straight from Computer A to Computer Z?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to both from Server1, mounting them on different mount points, then just copy the file like any other file.

It will tunnel the data through Server1 and put it on the target machine.